# Oracle Trigger update column with information from another column in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need to create a trigger in the yyy table. After a insert, I must update the test1 column with the same information of test2 column.

Could be like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_update

AFTER INSERT ON yyy FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE yyy SET TEST1 = :NEW.TEST2

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_update

    BEFORE INSERT ON yyy 
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

    :NEW.TEST1 := :NEW.TEST2;

    END;
/
```